# Spring Boot plugin doesn't add lib folder in jar

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jar

I have the following *build.gradle*:

```
group 'as'
version '1.0'

buildscript {
    ext {
        springVersion = '5.0.4.RELEASE'
        springBootVersion = '1.5.6.RELEASE'
        springJPAVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
        javaxVersion = '1.0.2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'reports'
    version =  '0.0.1'

    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': baseName,
                'Implementation-Version': version
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:${springJPAVersion}"
    implementation "javax.persistence:persistence-api:${javaxVersion}"
    implementation "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.43"

    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

And gradle creates jar with following structure:

- BOOT-INF

  - classes
- META-INF
- org

But it seems that the structure must be the following:

- BOOT-INF

  - classes
  - lib
- META-INF
- org

with lib folder, which contains dependencies, because now after launch I get error:

> Exception ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication at com.as.reports.Application.main(Application.java:12)

Answer (score 3):

So I know this answer is probably too late to help you, but I stumbled across this question while trying to solve the *exact* same problem, and was reminded of [this](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png).

After half a day of trial and error, I found the solution, so hopefully I can save someone else the pain of finding this unanswered question.

The problem is with using the `implementation` keyword in your dependencies.  The 1.x Spring Boot Gradle plugin doesn't appear recognize that keyword as notating required dependencies for repackaging a fat jar.  If you change those back to the older `compile` keyword, you should get the necessary lib folder.